# Laravel 5 - preg_match_all Issue

Tags: php, preg-match-all

So I've got the following code running when someone submits a post on my website (custom coded forum) but the issue I have is that if someone has a special character in their name (e.g. '-' '_' or ',' it won't register that for their name.

$content = what the user inserts into the body of the text, for example, if they want to tag Andy, they'd type @Andy in the body somewhere.

e.g. "@Andy how are you?" or, "When did this happen, @Andy?" and it will tag the user Andy, but say if a user has punctuation in their username, it won't tag them at all e.g. "@,Dennis how are you?" or, "When did this happen, @,Dennis?". Same happens for ones with punctuation inside it e.g. @Jodie-May

The code I am running is as below. I think it relates to the preg_match_all query, but basically, I want it to be able to pick up punctuation, but also continue along e.g. perhaps "Hey @,Dennis, hows @Janice and @-Dannie?" and I want it to tag Janice and -Dannie as well.

```
if(preg_match_all('/(?<=^|\s)@(\w+)/', $content, $match)) {
    foreach($match[1] as $usr) {
        -code here-
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mate and I worked on a fix for this, it is as below.

```
if(preg_match_all('/(?<FullMention>@(?<UsernameOnly>[a-zA-Z0-9,\-_]{1,}))/', $content, $match)) {
    foreach($match['UsernameOnly'] as $usr) {
        -code here-
    }
}
```

.

This has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore punctuation in tags name you can use this:

```
if(preg_match_all('/(\n|\s)+@[,\-_]*(\w+([,\-_]\w+)?)/', $content, $match)) {
    foreach($match[2] as $usr) {
        -code here-
    }
}
```

You can try it [here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/lST)

Comment: I'm actually looking for the complete opposite. So I want punctuation just after, the @ or during the name to be included in the preg_match_all but want so that after space (or newline) it relooks for another @ for the next one to add to an array.

Comment: `preg_match_all` will search into the entire text, you should begin your regex with `\n` to retrieve tags that start with return line, check my answer again

Comment: @Andrew, I edited my answer, You can accept it if it works for you :)